# CommandTimeout for OracleCommand

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, ado.net

I've found that the `CommandTimeout` property in `System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand` seems to be ignored.  I'm not able to use ODP.NET for my Oracle connections, but need to implement a timeout on my queries.

I'm not concerned about killing the actual queries on the database, just ending the process of executing the query after X seconds if the results have not been returned.

I've been playing with Threads and other ways to accomplish this, but certainly I'm not the first person to have this requirement.

Has anyone else come across this?  If so, what was your solution?

Comment: The CommandTimeout property does not work using the System.Data.OracleClient .NET 3.5 Provider. It appears that this functionality is not supported without the use of an external library.

Comment: Take a look at this this may help you http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/

Comment: The DevArt classes work for me.  Hopefully, I can talk my employer into the license!

Comment: good luck Paul If your employer wants it done based on your needs then hopefully this will work out for you