# How do I wait for an asynchronous event to be called?

Tags: c#

I have a method in C# that requires waiting for an event to occur.  It's sending data to a client, but it has to wait for an `event Action` to be fired (which is fired when a response packet is received).  How to I block execution of the method until the handler is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative would be to use a `TaskCompletionSource` See https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a30ff364-3435-4026-9f12-9bd9776c9a01/signalling-await?forum=async

It then becomes:

```
TaskCompletionSource tsc = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
Action handler = () => {
  //Do stuff
  tsc.SetResult(true);
}

Event += handler;
await tsc.Task;
Event -= handler;
```

The referenced discussion explains why this is a more lightweight solution.

Also, it won't block the thread and allows for a timeout (in case the event is not called) and/or cancellation (in case the application is closed down) by using a `CancellationTokenSource`, see [Timeout an async method implemented with TaskCompletionSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18760252/timeout-an-async-method-implemented-with-taskcompletionsource)

Comment: As it happens, I based my solution off of this - I just thought it would be faster to use wait handles.

Answer (score 2):

This solution worked nicely, and removes the handler from the event once it is no longer needed.

```
AutoResetEvent evt = new AutoResetEvent(false);
Action handler = () => {
  //Do stuff
  evt.Set();
}

Event += handler;
evt.WaitOne();
Event -= handler;
```

However, there is one major caveat (with a fairly easy workaround): **The calling thread will block indefinitely until the event is called.**  This means that if the event is never called, your program will hang.  The fix for this is to simply change `evt.WaitOne();` to `evt.WaitOne(SOME_TIMEOUT);`

Comment: If you're just waiting for one anyway, why not use ManualResetEventSlim? You don't really need it to reset, and Slim gives slightly better performance if you expect the response quickly.

Comment: Good question.  Probably should.